# Obtaining pointer to a string constant

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management, c89

```
short var = *((unsigned short*)&"BM");
```

`"BM"` must be located somewhere in read-only memory area then why can't I obtain a pointer to it? (It compiles but it says invalid memory area (clang compiler))

Comment: `char var = *((const char*)&"BM");` compiles on MSVC2012. I *think* this is well-formed. I think the behaviour of your example is undefined.

Comment: It returns `Read error in invalid memory area` which means it is trying to access memory address that doesn't exist or is read protected. Surprised it works on MSVC2012

Comment: `int main(){char var = *((const char*)&"BM"); printf("%c", var);}` compiles and runs on gcc 4.7.3

Comment: Behaviour is undefined because the address isn't guaranteed to be castable to a pointer type. The memory address of a constant string could be misaligned or located in read-only memory.

Comment: Are you sure about that? You can assign a `const char*` to it, and use that as an %s argument in printf.

Comment: @Bathsheba Since the size of `char` is 1, there is no such thing as a misaligned char pointer. gcc on x86 doesn't require any special alignment for short pointers, so it will work fine there. If you compile the code on another system, or even just with a different compiler, you could get another result.

Comment: Behavior is undefined, but first and foremost because the `&` operator is not applicable to literals.

Comment: And because the code violates a language constraint, it is not "well-formed" by any definition of that term that I would accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C does not permit taking the address of a literal:

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the `register` storage-class specifier.

-- C99 6.5.3.2/1

Literals do not fall into any of the permitted categories of operands.  This is a formal constraint of the language -- conforming implementations are not required to accept code that violates it, and *are* required to produce diagnostics describing violations.  C does not define the behavior of code that violates a constraint.

You can achieve something similar to what you seem to want like so:

```
union short_str {
    char str[3];
    int16_t sh;
} u = { "BM" };
short var = u.sh;
```

Among other things, this avoids the risk of dereferencing a pointer to misaligned storage.  C will align the storage for variable `u` so that all members are aligned on an appropriate boundary.  This avoids a possible pitfall with any approach along the lines you originally attempted.

Comment: Is that initialization legal in C89 ? It looks like an innovation to me.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck This is the only non-portable but fast enough way. The other is explicit casting (what the solution is attempting). But by removing the `&` - it works as long as it is assigned to a char.

Comment: i.e `short var = *((const short*)"BM");` throws a warning. And AFAIK.. warnings should be interpreted as errors in most of the cases.

Comment: The initializer is legal in C89.  The first element within the brackets is used to initialize the first member of the union.  I'm not sure whether the semantics are defined if there are multiple initializers in the brackets.

Comment: Thank you!! I can't believe I've finally learned something new!!

Comment: By the way it works without the brackets too. `u = "BM"`

Comment: Note, too, that reading from a different union member than was last written to involves implementation-defined behavior, but that because it must be true that `(void *) &u.str == (void *) &u.sh`, in practice this approach works pretty reliably.  Because it is *implementation*-defined (as opposed to *un*-defined), in the likely event that you find it to work, you can rely on it to continue to work.

Comment: I have some experience with unions. They seem to be widely used in image processing libraries.. which is what I am currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is of course:

```
short var= 0x424D;    // memory reads 4D, 42 = 'M', 'B'
```

or

```
short var= 0x4D42;    // memory reads 42, 4D = 'B', 'M'
```